# Subtract 2 nullable float type in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have two nullable float properties and I want to subtract them:

```
val dis1: Float? = 10.0f
val dis2: Float? = 5.0f

val value = dis1 - dis2
```

I created this extension function. But its going in infinite loop:

```
operator fun Float?.minus(dis2: Float?): Float {
  return this - dis2
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple you can use

```
operator fun Float?.minus(dis2: Float?): Float {
    return (this ?: 0f) - (dis2 ?: 0f)
}
```

**?:** checks if value is present if not then it assigns default value

> But its going in infinite loop

You extension is going in infinite loop because in return type again you are calling **-(Minus)**  on two nullable floats.

Answer (score 2):

**you don't do anything except calling the minus operator  that's way you get infinite loop**

make a null check and call the default minus operator of `Float`

```
  val dis1: Float? = 10.0f
  val dis2: Float? = 5.0f

  operator fun Float?.minus(dis2: Float?): Float {
        return (this ?: 0f) - (dis2 ?: 0f)

  val value = dis1 - dis2
```

Comment: The main reason I created this extension function is not use assertion. Any better solution?

Comment: that's weird if you don't want to make an assertion so what do you expect to be the outcome of null -1.0f or 7.0f - null? your operator  signature returning a Float

Answer (score 2):

You could just return 0 if the value is `null` to avoid a `KotlinNullPointerException`.
In your method:

```
fun minus(value1: Float?, value2: Float): Float{
   val firstValueHelper = value1 :? 0f
   val secondValueHelper = value2 :? 0f

   return firstValueHelper - secondValueHelper
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good if you want `null - null = 0` however if the case is you want `null - null = null` then you need something slightly different.

If the desired behaviour is:

- `10 - 5 = 5`
- `10 - null = 10`
- `null - 5 = -5`
- `null - null = null`

then use the following

```kotlin
operator fun Float?.minus(other: Float?): Float? { 
    return if (this == null && other == null) {
        null
    } else {
        (a ?: 0f) - (b ?: 0f)
    }
}
```

Note that addition can be achieved in a [similar way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64920775/8023278)