# What is the most readable way to sum two nullable Int in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, nullable

I tried to do something like the following:

```
val a: Int? = 1
val b: Int? = 1

a?.plus(b)
```

but it doesn't compile cause `plus` expects an `Int`.

I also tried to create a biLet function:

```
fun <V1, V2, V3> biLet(a: V1?, b: V2?, block: (V1, V2) -> V3): V3? {
    return a?.let {
        b?.let { block(a, b) }
    }
}
```

and use it like that:

```
val result = biLet(a, b) { p1, p2 -> p1 + p2 }
```

but it seems a lot of work for something apparently simple. Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: `b?.let {a?.plus(it)}` works

Comment: I moved my comment down to one of the answers. What I mean is, if I see `val c = a + b` for two nullable `Int`s, it is not obvious if `c` is nullable, and it is not obvious what happens if `a` or `b` is nullable. Maybe the `+` operator makes them default to `0` when null, or maybe `-1`, or maybe it even throws an IllegalArgumentException. Maybe it simply returns `0` if either number is `null`. These are all possibly desired behaviors depending on context. But if it's a small class and the operator function is kept private to the class, no big deal.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm not aware of a theory about nullable types which defines operations. I would consider reasonable to define any operation between nullable types as having a null result if both operands are null.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't anything already in the standard library to sum two nullable ints.

What you can do, however, is to create an `operator fun` for a nullable `Int?`:

```kotlin
operator fun Int?.plus(other: Int?): Int? = if (this != null && other != null) this + other else this ?: other
```

And then, you can use it normally like the not-null version:

```kotlin
val a: Int? = 2
val b: Int? = 3
val c = a + b
```

If you don't want to create a function for it, you can always use its body to handle the nullability of the two ints.

Answer (score 8):

Well, for me this one looks the more readable,

```kotlin
val result = if (a != null && b != null) a+b else null
```

And when one is null other is not-null and you just want the non-null value then maybe like this:

```kotlin
val result = (a?:0)+(b?:0)
```

Comment: PS: the second one will be 0 if both were null.

Comment: This is for sure the most readable way if they're both local variables or read-only properties. It clearly shows the behvaior. Member vars would be trickier. The operator function idea in the other answer sure is concise, but masks how it treats nullability so I'd say readability is questionable. I'd go so far to say that for `var` properties you should create local `val` copies and then use this solution. Verbose, but very clear behavior.

Comment: @Tenfour04 " The operator function idea in the answers sure is concise, but masks how it treats nullability so I'd say readability is questionable." Could you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: @DiegoMarin I answered you up top.

Comment: I like this the best as it makes the semantics explicit. The result of adding a null number is undefined, so hiding the "if it's null we're going to coerce it to zero" behind some operator implementation isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends what the expected output of adding nulls is.

Should `4 + null = null` or `4 + null = 4`? and what about `null + null`?

In my case what I was after is:

- `4 + 3 = 7`
- `4 + null = 4`
- `null + null = null`

The below function achieves this behaviour

```kotlin
private fun addNullable(a: Int?, b: Int?): Int? {
    return if (a == null && b == null) {
        null
    } else {
        (a ?: 0) + (b ?: 0)
    }
}

...

val a: Int? = 1
val b: Int? = 1
val result = addNullable(a, b)
```

Alternatively you can use an [operator overload](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) if you want this same behaviour everywhere. The disadvantage of this is when using it it's not clear it's custom behaviour.

```kotlin
operator fun Int?.plus(other: Int?): Int? { 
    return if (this == null && other == null) {
        null
    } else {
        (a ?: 0) + (b ?: 0)
    }
}

...

val a: Int? = 1
val b: Int? = 1
val result = a + b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listOfNotNull(int1, int2, int3).sumOfOrNull { it }
```

Where the ints are Int?

Comment: Something like that does not exist :)

Answer (score 0):

I think other answers are better than this, but I would like to give a hint with a solution that can easily scale up to other types and necessities, the one using the library called [Arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/core/), with `Option` and `Semigroup`:

```
val a: arrow.core.Option<Int> = Some(1)
val b: Option<Int> = 1.toOption() // it's the same

val sum: Int? = Semigroup.option(Semigroup.int()).run {
    a + b
  }.orNull()
```

Semigroup can be very useful (you can concatenate lists without caring of nulls) and preserve the actual operator you want to use.